# Translator Text API　について

Tags: unity3d, api, azure

Translator Text API を使ったアプリを制作中です。
Unity2017.2　で制作を進めているのですが、
API利用のためのトークンの取得でエラーがかえってきます。
エラー内容：Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API

ここに書いてある方法はすべて試したのですが、うまくいきません。
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2017/05/17/http-401-access-denied-when-calling-azure-cognitive-services-apis/

実装方法など間違っていますでしょうか？
解決策をご存知の方おられましたら助けてください。

This is my code:

```
private IEnumerator GetAccessTokenForTranslation()
{

        string subscriptionKey = <my key>;

        string url = "http://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken";

        List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
        formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("Accept", "application/jwt"));
        formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey));

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`に関してはフォームデータとしてではなく、**リクエストヘッダ**に含める必要がありそうです。

英語版Stackoverflowでの関連質問(JavaScriptでの例)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467976/2322778

Comment: keyに関して、フォームデータから除き、ヘッダに含めると無事解決しました！ありがとうございました！